# "failed to solve: operating system is not supported" when creating amd64 docker image on ARM mac

Tags: linux, docker, apple-m1

I'm under the impression that docker on an M1/M2 Mac (using aarch64/ARM architecture) supports building amd64 containers. And it does seem to build them just fine.

But after building the container, it fails on the very last step:

`docker buildx build --platform x86_64 -t dark`

```
Building docker image
[+] Building 1.6s (68/68) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:7cc0576c7c  1.4s
 => [ 1/64] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:7cc0576c7c0ec2384de5cbf245  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:7cc0576c7c0ec2384de5cbf245f4  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/64] RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive     apt update --allow-rele  0.0s
-- ignore 62 steps here for brevity --
 => CACHED [64/64] RUN mkdir -p       /home/dark/.vscode-server/extensions         0.0s
 => ERROR exporting to image                                                       0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                            0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:4c0b1a1acd5c0c3c87ec9e2aa2c34cff9b6b698b83bfb6d0d10ff  0.0s
------
 > exporting to image:
------
error: failed to solve: operating system is not supported
```

How can I fix this?

### Versions

`uname -a`:

> Darwin cotedor.lan 21.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:29 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64 arm Darwin

`docker --version`:

> Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086

Docker for Mac:

> 4.8.2 (79419), Engine: 20.10.14

OS: macOS 12.4 Monterey, on M1 (2020)

Comment: Disappointing that there's no replies to this! :(

Answer (score 2):

Enabling "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" under "Features in development" in Docker setting worked for me.